# Erase USB in Disk Utility says "Permission denied"

Tags: macos, usb, disk-format

I'm trying to format my USB so I can get all the space back onto it, but every time I try to erase it in Disk Utility, this comes up:

> POSIX reports: The operation couldn’t be completed. Permission denied

Comment: Are you erasing the disk or the main partition?

Answer (score 1):

Try with diskutil:

```
diskutil eraseVolume HFS+ "new name" disk1
```

<sup>Replace `new name` with the name you wish the disk to have, and `disk1` with the disk identifier (select disk → Info).</sup>

Comment: tried this method, but got `Error: -69888: Couldn't unmount disk`

Comment: Try force unmounting by entering `diskutil force unmount disk1` in terminal.

Answer (score -1):

Although it may seem unintuitive, try formatting the drive using a Windows computer. Then, take the now (Windows) formatted drive over to the Mac and  format it there - it will work.

It's has happened to me many times too, but the speed of this method has always greatly outweighed any further research time.

I hope that helps you out, however, the question of what causes this error could be one of many... hence, if you need a formatted drive now, this will work.
But do let me know how you get on.